# npm http-server alternative ports

Tags: node.js, npm

We have a number of projects that use http-server and Express to server different project components on different ports i.e.: user interface on `8080` and some API on `4040`.

Now, I often have a number of different projects running at a time and these all want to use `8080` for their user interface and `4040` for their APIs.

Does http-server (https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) have a default process for selecting alternative ports? And if not, can anyone suggest an npm package to offer that?

Ultimately I want: Project one UI `8080` and API `4040` and project two UI `8081` and API `4041`. Or something similar.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can try using  [Node-Static](https://github.com/cloudhead/node-static/blob/master/README.md) for UIs , i assume since it's just static content.

A process monitoring manager such as [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io) to start your projects.

Also you can set/get environmental variables for each project/UI ports variables.

```
process.env.PROJECT_ONE_UI_PORT
process.env.PROJECT_ONE_API_PORT
process.env.PROJECT_TWO_UI_PORT
process.env.PROJECT_TWO_API_PORT
```

An helpful article is [here](https://blog.risingstack.com/node-js-project-structure-tutorial-node-js-at-scale) checkout the section where configuration is handled.

Another way is to handle errors if the port is already in use but that might break stuff for other services like UI is looking in wrong URL  for api. In this case you might reconsider your architecture and use service discovery with an webserver to dynamically use other ports an rebuild configurations. I believe that might be an overkill thought if you lack the knowledge for it.